# BCNF - Normal Form

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

Wondering if you think the following table for storing employees in a database would be consider a database in BCNF ?

```
- Employee Table

Employee_ID (Primary Key, unique) 
First_Name
Surname
Religion 
Sex
Job Title
Nationality 

 - Employee_Address Table

Employee_ID (Foreign Key)
Line_One_Address
Line_Two_Address
District
Country

 - Employee_Conact Table

Employee_ID (Foreign Key)
Mobile_Number
```

So my question is do you think this will meet the critria for being in BCNF ? Or should I have a Nationaility table, Job Title Table, Religion table etc. as they will be duplicate information in the db for it

I am just new to the learning normilzation, so any thoughts and tips will be helpful

Comment: What definition are you using for BCNF?

Comment: Your question is asking for a section or more of an introductory college/university textbook/course. There are many online.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest renaming the EMPLOYEE table to PERSON
then you will notice that job title does not belong with the person definiton- so at least that one should be in another table - like a linking table between people and organizations - where you would put the title and hire date etc.